Skip corrupted entries on table insert with python library pandas
I use Pandas dataframe to read and upload a CSV file to a structured database table. During the upload, I first read in chunks and then try to insert these chunks. My next idea to make this work flawlessly is to also convert the resulting dataframe into chunks and insert in a more safe pace.
I insert the file content using the method pandas.DataFrame.to_sql. The specific method does not offer a property like insert_row_if_valid, which would bring ease to ongoing corrupted entries. Instead, it outputs an error as below:
The created table does not comply with data type, which raises the error
(psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type double precision

Do you have some bullet proof approach to insert data and skip ONLY the corrupted entries?

what is considered a corrupted entry? can you not clean the data before exporting it?

The specific issue you see is an improper string representation of a float value e.g. select  ''::float; invalid input syntax for type double precision: "". One way to deal with this create a staging table that has all varchar fields and import into that and then clean up the values in the table before moving to the final table.

@AdrianKlaver I use pandas to perform this insert query. I will follow your advice.

@AdrianKlaver The weird part for me is that only a 'roten apple' inside a chunk corrupts it all.

On the PostgreSQL side, you could use COPY with the option ON_ERROR ignore, available from v17 on.
